# How to iterate over the last td of every tr in a HTML table until the next tr have certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a HTML table like this

```html
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th> column1 </th>
   <th> column2 </th>
   <th> total column </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-caption"> title of the grouped rows 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> value 1</td>
    <td class="total_class"> row total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td> Total </td>
   <td class="total_tr"> the sum of the rows total <td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="td-caption"> title of the grouped rows 2 </td>
  </tr>
 . . .
 <tbody>
</table>
```

So I need to add the values of 'total_class' and put it in `total_tr`, but if the next tr has class `td-caption`, the `total_tr` should end there and start again for the next section

I already have this little code to get the totals, but I'm not starting the total from 0 for each section, so the totals keep adding up to the end

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            // Loop through each div element with the class total_class
            let numbers = [] 
            $(".total_class").each(function(){
                
                // Check the td is not empty
                if($(this).is(":empty")){
                    $(this).css("background", "yellow");
                } else {
                    // get the numbers of every td, parse to int and add to numbers array
                   let number = $(this).text();
                   let intnum = parseInt(number);
                   numbers.push(intnum);
                }
            });
            // Loop over number's array to get the total
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i <numbers.length; i++) {
                total +=numbers[i] << 0;
            }
            
            // Display on total_tr 
            $('.total_tr').text(total);
        });
```

Comment: Do you have more than one element with the id "total_tr"? That's invalid HTML and you'll find jQuery will only change the first element with that id. You should probably also consider check if `!isNaN(intnum)` before pushing into `numbers`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, but I'm already change it to a class, and updated my question